# Are there any reasons I should not have 2 files in apache to manage vhosts?

Tags: apache, apache2

On a Linux based web server I have Apache2 running and in my current `httpd.conf` file I have the following:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

In httpd-ssl.conf I manage all of my vhost details.  Currently there are ~15  entries in there and I need to add more.

I'd like to have a second file, call it `httpd-ssl2.conf` that would contain nothing but specific  entries in an attempt to help keep things a little more organized.

Are there any reasons not to do this that I should be thinking of?

Comment: I would say that there are not only no problems with this, but it is actually best-practice to keep one vhost (or closely related set of vhosts) per file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any reasons not to do this that I should be thinking of?

Nothing wrong with this. A lot of distributions and installs of Apache do this already. For example, on gentoo's Apache2, it has these lines in the `httpd.conf`:

```
Include /etc/apache2/modules.d/*.conf
Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/*.conf
```

And you can create as many ssl or non-ssl vhosts in separate files or all in one file in the `/vhosts.d` directory. You can organize them any way that you want. If you don't want to use a `*.conf` and want to be more explicit (which might be a little safer) you can just add each .conf file explicitly in your `httpd.conf`:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl2.conf
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to go with the named file, like your second example, to help keep things in order.